# Terraform load balancer with multiple listeners

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Given this Terraform script for creating an AWS Elastic Load Balancer:

```
resource "aws_elb" "elb" {
  name = "${var.elb_name}"
  subnets = ["${var.subnet_ids}"]
  internal = "${var.elb_is_internal}"
  security_groups = ["${var.elb_security_group}"]

  listener {
    instance_port = "${var.backend_port}"
    instance_protocol = "${var.backend_protocol}"
    lb_port = 80
    lb_protocol = "http"
  }

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    timeout = 3
    target = "${var.health_check_target}"
    interval = 30
  }

  cross_zone_load_balancing = true
}
```

How would it be modified to create multiple listeners?

Comment: Are you saying you want to control the amount of listener blocks dynamically? Because unfortunately it's not possible to do that. You'd need a separate aws_elb_listener resource that enables you to define listeners separately to the ELB and use those to configure the ELB but that resource doesn't exist (and I'm not sure it's actually practically possible).

Comment: there is actually some activity on this issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9807. So while it is not possible to do now, hopefully it will make it into a future release.

Comment: You can't currently do this with the ELB, as the `aws_elb` resource only allows inline blocks for listeners. However, you can do it with the new ALB, as the `aws_alb` resource allows you to define listeners in separate `aws_alb_listener` resources. You could combine those with the `count` parameter and your variable to generate them dynamically. See [Terraform tips & tricks: loops, if-statements, and gotchas](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9) for examples with `count`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass a list of maps to the listener.

```
listener = [{
    instance_port = "${var.backend_port}"
    instance_protocol = "${var.backend_protocol}"
    lb_port = 80
    lb_protocol = "http"
  },{
    instance_port = "${var.backend2_port}"
    instance_protocol = "${var.backend2_protocol}"
    lb_port = 8080
    lb_protocol = "http"
  }]
```

Alternatively,

```
listener = ["${var.elb_listeners}"]
```

where `var.elb_listeners` is a list of map as in the first example above.